# Does Android continuously notify the user to update the OS?

Tags: updates

I am wondering if Android notifies the user daily to update their OS like Apple's iOS does?  I'm a long term iOS user and the automatic software updates implemented recently has me considering switching over to Android.     I've never used or owned an Android and am curious what the experience is like.

Comment: I think this is manufacturer dependent (some have custom updaters). Just be informed that usually only flagships receive more than one update.

Answer (score 1):

Daily updates **no**, but it does depend upon the device provider. That is they have to customise the OS to suite the device.

My experience, on a Lenovo Tablet, is that updates are pretty low in frequency, less than on a monthly basis and applying the OS updates is not compulsory.

Answer (score 1):

As MikeT said, it depends on the device.

For tbe most part, No matter how much a device screams, you can ignore the update. You can also disable auto checks and get no notifications until you check yourself.

That said though, it depends. Samsung rarely do updates, like quite a few OEMS. Google Updates the Nexus line Every month, though it is optional security updates that take little time to do.

The reason updates are so off-hand is because of a system app called 'Google Play Services', which does a lot more than I can explain. It negotiates app connections, Grants the user to use GApps and the API'S included, and can add new features-no OS update needed. Neat, eh?

-EDIT- If you like a good read, [have a look at this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/179638/not-getting-android-os-updates-heres-how-google-is-updating-your-device-anyway/)